# Produce INSTANT from different date-string formats

Tags: java, date-parsing

I need to convert date string into an Instant and these three format I am expecting from my users

- yyyy-MM-dd
- yyyy-MM
- yyyy

Converting **yyyy-MM-dd** to an instant wasn't that hard

```
Optional.ofNullable(request.getDate())
                .map(LocalDate::parse)
                .map(date -> date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toInstant())
                .map(pojo::dateAsInstant)
```

However, I am struggling to find the solution to parse the other two formats into a java.time.Instant. Can someone please help?

Comment: Well, which instant are you expecting to convert the other two to?  You'd need to know what month and day you require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) and its [`parseDefaulting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-), together with optional sections in the format string.

#### LocalDate

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-08-13", fmt)); // Prints: 2019-08-13
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-08"   , fmt)); // Prints: 2019-08-01
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019"      , fmt)); // Prints: 2019-01-01
```

Or the long version not using pattern string.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalEnd()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US);
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-08-13", fmt)); // Prints: 2019-08-13
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019-08"   , fmt)); // Prints: 2019-08-01
System.out.println(LocalDate.parse("2019"      , fmt)); // Prints: 2019-01-01
```

#### ZonedDateTime

With 2 extra defaults, you can parse straight to a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US)
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08-13", fmt)); // 2019-08-13T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-08"   , fmt)); // 2019-08-01T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("2019"      , fmt)); // 2019-01-01T00:00-05:00[America/New_York]
```

#### Instant

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) doesn't have a `parse` method taking a formatter, so the parse call is slightly different.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendPattern("uuuu[-MM[-dd]]")
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US)
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019-08-13", Instant::from)); // 2019-08-13T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019-08"   , Instant::from)); // 2019-08-01T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019"      , Instant::from)); // 2019-01-01T05:00:00Z
```

#### Instant with optional dashes

Couldn't get this working using a pattern, but works fine using the long way to build the formatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4)
        .optionalStart()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 2)
        .optionalStart()
        .optionalStart()
        .appendLiteral('-')
        .optionalEnd()
        .appendValue(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2)
        .optionalEnd()
        .optionalEnd()
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_DAY, 0)
        .toFormatter(Locale.US)
        .withZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019-08-13", Instant::from)); // 2019-08-13T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("20190813"  , Instant::from)); // 2019-08-13T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019-08"   , Instant::from)); // 2019-08-01T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("201908"    , Instant::from)); // 2019-08-01T04:00:00Z
System.out.println(fmt.parse("2019"      , Instant::from)); // 2019-01-01T05:00:00Z
```

Comment: question: why the outputs have hour differences? 04:00:00 & 05:00:00 and how did it work just by adding SECOND_OF_DAY without adding HOUR and MINUTES_OF_DAY?

Comment: @AMagic The hours are different because of Daylight Savings Time. In the `America/New_York` time zone, August is in Daylight time (EDT), while January is in Standard time (EST).  --- It works because `SECOND_OF_DAY` (0-86399) is not the same as `SECOND_OF_MINUTE` (0-59), similar to how `DAY_OF_YEAR` (1-366) is not the same as `DAY_OF_MONTH` (1-31).

Comment: I see. Thanks! I fixed that by `fmt.parse("2019-08-13", Instant::from).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`

Comment: So, this parses the dates with dashes in them. What should I do to parse something like `201908` into `2019-08-01T00:00:00Z` ?

Comment: @AMagic Make the dashes *optional*: `[-]`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I did this `uuuu[-]MM[-]dd` and `uuuu[[-]MM[[-]dd]]`

Comment: @AMagic Not sure why, but it works if you use the long style instead of the pattern to build the formatter.